# Unable to load suggested edit - please try again repeatedly

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

During reviewing the Stack Overflow questions (not from the Review Queues), I seen there was a pending edit for approval:

[image: Pending Edit Unable to Load]

It was a very peculiar stuff, it never happened before and the fun fact is that it did only happen to the specific question, nowhere else. Whenever I tried to open the pending edit of that question, I got the error:

```
Unable to load suggested edit - please try again
```

I did try refreshing the browser which didn't solve it. Restarted browser and tried, but still failed. I wonder if this is a bug that never happened. For clarity, **this problem didn't occur in any other question.**

Comment: Ah, can you access the review queues currently? The suggested edits queue specifically

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Of course, yes. **Note:** The question's suggested edit has been approved by another reviewer.

Comment: This issue is network-wide. Here's the [bug report on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351183/unable-to-load-suggested-edit-please-try-again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was a network-wide bug which occurred on Stack Exchange networks for a few hours. This problem was firstly posted on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351183/unable-to-load-suggested-edit-please-try-again) before this post.

Site developers have successfully fixed it now.